# How to retrieve updated data from gridview dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I populated the gridview with datatable like this:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    FillGrid();
 }

public void FillGrid() {
    foreach (ListItem item in lblType.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            DataTable data = AppDataAccess.GetData(item.Value, txtid.Value);
            GridView1.DataSource = data;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```

It's not possible to retrieve the updated data like the following because data comes from several DB tables.

```
  protected void grdContact_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int index = GridView1.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
    TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
    TextBox t2 = row.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
    string t3 = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    lblRecord.Text = "Updated record " + t1.Text + "," + t2.Text + "Value From Bound Field" + t3;
}
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the updated data dynamically from Gridview rows?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your question. its not sufficient to understand me...

Comment: @sehtaumesh The gridview is populated with dynamic data and so,the columns of gridview are changing dynamically according to the datatable. I wanna retrieve all updated rows' data and their respective column names. The problem is that I only know how to get data with findcontrol method.